# Google Maps conflict dependency in Gradle

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have tried to add a Google Map fragment to my android app. I add the dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
```

However when I try to sync the gradle build file I get the error

```
Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. 
Resolved versions for app (22.2.0) and test app (23.0.1) differ.
```

On the advice of another stack overflow answer we ran the Gradle dependencies report, and found that the only package that includes the module 22.2.0 is the google play one itself.

I have tried to exclude the module but this is to no avail.

Has anyone solved this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

I attach the relevant part of the build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//./compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.4') {
        exclude module: 'support annotations'
    }
    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.4') {
        exclude module: 'support annotations'
    }
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1') {
        exclude module: 'support annotations'
    }
    // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not excluding the support annotations module from your testing libraries because of a small typo.  Change "support annotations" to "support-annotations" in your exclude statements.

```
exclude module: 'support-annotations'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - can't believe we missed that

Answer (score 0):

Huh! Faced this issue in the morning and now seeing this question.

I resolved by adding the following additional dependency:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.+'
```

I was not sure of the correct resolving version thereby kept with wildcard '+', if you are sure replace the wildcard with the right one.